# Redirect is not working with onClick method in anchor tag

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router, react-router-dom

I want to use a div as my button and here is the code for that :

```
<a onClick={handleLogin()}>
    <div   className="blu-button">
     <p  id="button-text-blu">LOGIN AS ADMIN <span role="img" aria-label="emoji"> </span></p>
     <div  className="blu-button-wrapper"></div>
    </div>
</a>
```

And here is my `handleLogin` function :

```
const handleLogin = () => {
      return <Redirect to="/amnet/auth"/>
}
```

The browser is not throwing any error. It's just the Redirect thing that's not working. I have already tried console logging the thing and it worked.

P.S. The application is being developed in React.

Comment: use `history` instead of `Redirect`

Comment: `onClick` cannot directly update the content of `render() {}`, you simply can't return JSX from an event handler. Instead have a boolean state flag that is adjusted then with conditional rendering, return the appropriate `Render` component inside `render() {}`. Otherwise use the suggestions in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Use `useHistory` hook if you have a functional component

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
```

```
let history = useHistory();
```

```
const handleLogin = () => {
      history.push("/amnet/auth")
}
```

if class-based component:

```
const handleLogin = () => {
      this.props.history.push("/amnet/auth")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using props.history.push instead of the redirect component.

If you absolutely must use the redirect component (for example if you're on react < 16.3) you need to conditionally render the  component within the rendering function of the component the button is in